# Position finder on v2

Tags: overleaf

Ive been trying overleaf v2, but it seems like theres not a position finder module working, like synctex.

Is it some sort of bug with me? Is it an upcoming feature not existing in the current beta? Or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: I think that between tex and pdf windows there exist two arrow icons that you can press to move from one to the other. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to do it in Overleaf v2:

Position the cursor on .tex file and press

[image]

or position pdf result and press

[image]